# Aristotle wheel paradox

Tags: rotation, angular-velocity

Please, can someone explain to me in detail the working of Aristotle wheel paradox? I find it amazing and I am thinking on my own of its working. Could someone shed some light here and enlighten me?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristotle%27s_wheel_paradox

Comment: This is mathematics / geometry, not physics. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2814598/207316

Comment: @PM 2Ring. Indeed, the physics is trivial and straightforward: if a no-slip rubber rod were placed on top of the small wheel, it would be pushed forward much *less* than the distance traveled. It is a philosopher's math problem...

Answer (score 1):

It is not a paradox at all. The missing part of the puzzle is that the smaller wheel's center of rotation is moving at a rate set by the rotation of the *larger* wheel; if the smaller wheel were in close contact with the ground while this were taking place, you could see that it would be skidding along the ground and not rolling without slippage.